# Mysql Master Master replication. When changes are made on server offline

Tags: php, mysql

I have implemented a Master Master replication between my local and live. The requirement here is the client needs to make changes offline and the customers can make orders through live.

What I need is when an order with ID 100 is edited on both local(offline) and live. And the connection between master and local get re-established the update query must run in an order. ie if ID 100 is edited at 1.00 am in local(offline) and same record is edited at 2.00 am in live. Now when the local becomes online and sync, then the last edit(edited 2.00 am in live) must be the final record(ID 100) in both the databases(Live and local).

How can I do this with Mysql? Or Is there a way to do this with php?

Comment: What stops you from recording the timestamp of the last update in a TIMESTAMP field and just use the newer row?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I can do this with php. But is it possible using mysql? Because what happens now is when the local comes offline->online local changes are sent to live and live changes are sent to local so its creating a mess. is there any way so that the last change comes into effect?

Comment: Ofcourse! Just use BEFORE UPDATE and BEFORE INSERT triggers.

Comment: this is bad idea to write to both masters simultaneously

Comment: Basically,The idea of Master_Master Replication is to have an active master and a Passive master,where all the insertion and all operations to be done on the active master and the copy is made in the passive server, so as @akuzminsky pointed,writing to both masters is a bad approach

Comment: Thanks, Then what kind of replication do you think is the best so that I can have a local(Pc) database(can go offline for some time) and a live database. If you want me to have a third database to sync the changes between the local pc and live database, Can you please point me to some direction?